# Outline editing, like org-mode, for JSON

Tags: code-folding, json, outline

I am trying to edit a Swagger JSON file in emacs. It contains large nested JSON objects, so I want to collapse and hide some of them.

I have tried `origami-mode`, configured as `origami-c-style-parser` in `origami-parser-alist`, but it is quite unsophisticated (the word "parser" seems to be an overly grandiose word for what it does). It doesn't notice that Swagger URL parameter substrings like `{id}` are inside JSON strings, so it happily collapses them too when I ask it to collapse all nodes in the buffer except the current node. I don't want it to do that. I want a way of collapsing only JSON subtrees like objects, not substrings of JSON strings that *happen* to have curly braces in them. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but it is quite possible that `js2-mode` has folding that can also fold JSON files.

Comment: Related: [Code-folding extensions for json](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7361/code-folding-extensions-for-json).

Comment: One approach is to convert your json into some similar tree format and operate on that. This can convert into xml https://github.com/hay/xml2json. Yaml would be another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs comes with hs-minor-mode which can be used selectively hide/show code and comment blocks in several languages, including JavaScript.  By default this will let you hide and show JSON blocks delimited by '{' and '}' but it is easily modified to allow '[' and ']' as block delimeters as well.  To do this we need to modify the `js-mode` entry in `hs-special-modes-alist` with something like:

```
(setcdr (assoc 'js-mode hs-special-modes-alist) '("[{[]" "[}\\]]" "/[*/]" nil))
```

You should then find that [...] blocks can be hidden and shown as well as {...} blocks.

Answer (score 0):

[My `json-mode`](https://github.com/dominela10/json-mode) has a code folding feature which shouldn't try to fold things that look like Objects or Arrays inside of strings. It's not a mature major-mode, but it should be usable.